# Is there a way to simplify incremental calculations in acrobat?

Tags: acrobat

Other than using a long string of if statements is there a way to program an acrobat text box to incrementally calculate based on variables entered into an other text box?
Here is what I have.

```
 var v = this.getField("FixNum").value;

 if (v == "1")
 {
 event.value = 84 ;
 }
 else if (v == "2")
 {
 event.value = 88 ;
 }
 else if (v == "3")
 {
 event.value = 92 ;
 }
 else
 {
 event.value = "";
 }
```

As you can see this will get cumbersome because this goes from 1 - 9 in this pattern where 9 = 116, then 10 - 100 where 10 = 135. After 100 the pattern is 495 + 6 for every unit i.e. 101 = 501. I hope someone can understand this because I can't think of another way to ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several possibilities:

• If you can come up with a formula, it would be simplest.

• If the value pairs are arbitrary, you might create a lookup table (in form of an array).

• If the input numbers are (more or less) consecutive integers, you can work with a simple array, where the index is the input number, and the element with that index number is the output number.

• If it is more complicated, you would have to create a 2-dimensional array, where each element is an array of input and output number.

• If you are looking for a simple replacement of if…else if statements, you can use the switch… statement, which would work well for totally arbitrary value pairs.

**Update**, following the comment by OP:

According to a comment by the OP, the input numbers are consecutive, which means that the third point above would be the method of choice. For that, proceed as follows:

Create a document-level script (the name does not matter):

```
var myPricesArr = [0, 12, 15, 17, 23, 27, 30, 33] ;
```

alternate possibility:

```
var myPricesArr = new Array() ;
myPricesArr[0] = 0 ;
myPricesArr[1] = 12 ;
myPricesArr[2] = 15 ;
myPricesArr[3] = 17 ;
myPricesArr[4] = 23 ;
myPricesArr[5] = 27 ;
myPricesArr[6] = 30 ;
myPricesArr[7] = 33 ;
```

Both variants are equivalent, but the second one is easier to maintain, but requires more typing…

Create a text field named "numFixts", formatted as number, no decimals, maybe with a maximum value (to protect the form from failing).

Create a text field named "fixtsAmt, formatted as number. In the Calculate event of this field add the following JavaScript:

```
event.value = myPricesArr[this.getField("numFixts").value] ;
```

And that should do it.

Comment: I'll give that a try. The input numbers represent the number of fixtures in a house so not random. The output is the actual cost of a permit based on the input number. I'll study on how to program arrays. This site has been awesome. Thanks.

Comment: OK, in this case, you could follow the third line, creating a simple array (see edited answer for a possible syntax.

Comment: Great. I'll give this a try and let you know how it works.